# Jenkins WorkflowScript: Loading libraries failed

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-groovy, lib

I am using jenkins as my CI/CD and this suddenly started to happen. Jenkins file loads libraries from different repository but located on the same git account and it was working fine. Now all the declarative pipelines not working and throwing this weird error.

Jenkins version: 2.263.3
Java 11
Jenkinsfile:
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

@Library('jenkins-shared-library') _

MyPipeline()

````
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.lambda$retrieve$0(SCMSourceRetriever.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.retrySCMOperation(SCMSourceRetriever.java:98)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.SCMSourceRetriever.retrieve(SCMSourceRetriever.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryAdder.retrieve(LibraryAdder.java:157)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryAdder.add(LibraryAdder.java:138)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryDecorator$1.call(LibraryDecorator.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1065)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: Loading libraries failed

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE ```
````

Answer (score 2):

Can you check in : manage jenkins > configure system > Global Pipeline Libraries ?
You should have something like this:
[image]

Comment: I was unable to solve this problem, so I reverted my setup to a backup taken two weeks ago and now the builds are working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I just lost a good fistful of my hair trying to find the cause of this error before I realized that it happened because I had a parameter named `path` for the pipeline. For some unholy reason, this overwrote the system `PATH` variable inside the script that checks out the library.

The root error I got (i.e. the cause of `WorkflowScript: Loading libraries failed`) was:

```
stderr: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/my-job@libs/my-library@tmp/jenkins-gitclient-ssh2579541546742439932.sh-copy: 6: ssh: not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this note, some hair pulling took place here for the same reason!

Answer (score 1):

One thing I want to add here is, you need to add the shared libraries at the root level or at the folder level. You can't really add at the Job level